# Force IMPORTED target to use absolute path to .so file even when it is located in a subfolder of project root

Tags: cmake, linker, dynamic-linking

I have the following directory structure

```
.
├── 3rdparty
│   └── liba
│       ├── include
│       │   └── liba.hpp
│       └── lib
│           └── liba.so
├── cmake
│   └── FindLiba.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
└── source
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

Here, `liba` is a commercial, closed-source third-party library. Unfortunately, the vendor of the library doesn't provide a CMake config for their library, so I wrote my own find module:

```
# cmake/FindLiba.cmake

# - Try to find liba
# Once done, this will define
#
#  Liba_FOUND - system has liba
#  Liba_INCLUDE_DIRS - the liba include directories
#  Liba_LIBRARIES - link these to use liba

# Include dir
find_path(Liba_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES liba.hpp
)

# Finally the library itself
find_library(Liba_LIBRARY
  NAMES a
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
# handle the QUIETLY and REQUIRED arguments and set Liba_FOUND to TRUE
# if all listed variables are TRUE
find_package_handle_standard_args(Liba  DEFAULT_MSG
                                  Liba_LIBRARY Liba_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(Liba_INCLUDE_DIR Liba_LIBRARY)

set(Liba_INCLUDE_DIRS ${Liba_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(Liba_LIBRARIES ${Liba_LIBRARY})

if (NOT TARGET Liba::Liba) 
    add_library(Liba::Liba SHARED IMPORTED) 
    set_target_properties(Liba::Liba PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${Liba_LIBRARIES} 
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ${Liba_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )
endif()
```

Since `main.cpp` makes use of this library, the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `source` folder looks like this:

```
find_package(Liba REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

# VERSION 1
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE Liba::Liba)

# VERSION 2
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE ${Liba_LIBRARIES})
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${Liba_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

To build the entire thing I use `cmake -Bbuild -H. -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=${PWD}/3rdparty/liba && cmake --build build`.

The problem I have is the following: With version 1, the compiled binary `build/source/main` links to `../3rdparty/liba/liba.so`, as can be seen in the output of `ldd`:

```
ldd build/source/main
    [...]
    ../3rdparty/liba/lib/liba.so => not found
    [...]
```

With version 2, `main` links against `liba.so` without the relative path, but the rpath seems to be set such that it can still be found:

```
ldd build/source/main
    [...]
    liba.so => /home/manuel/development/demo/3rdparty/liba/lib/liba.so (0x00007f2a4c3f3000)
    [...]
```

The second version is preferable, as with version 1 the executable can be run only when the current working directory is `build`, `cmake`, `3rdparty` or `source`, otherwise the shared library can't be found. In particular, I can't just run `./build/source/main` after the project is built.

Interestingly enough, this seems only to be an issue because `liba` is located within the project subtree. When I move `liba` outside of the project directory and adjust the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH accordingly, it also works fine. But I'd like to keep it where it currently is just so that is is part of the git repository and versioned with the `main.cpp` that uses it.

Is there a way to configure the IMPORTED target `Liba` in such a way that just adding it to the `target_link_libraries` causes CMake to behave the same way as it does when adding `${Liba_LIBRARIES}` instead?

Comment: I hit this issue, and worked around it by defining a dummy STATIC library instead of importing the library. I then set the INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARYIES of that dummy target to include the full path to the library I wanted to link against.

Comment: FYI: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.14/prop_tgt/IMPORTED_NO_SONAME.html